# BROWSER option is missing in view listener in a tree in JMeter

Tags: http, jmeter, listener, http-live-streaming

I have JDK 14 and JMeter 5.3 configured on my Windows 64 bit system But I don't see "Browser" option in "View Listeners in a Tree" in JMeter.

Any ways I can get it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is just to downgrade to [Oracle JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) as it includes [JavaFX](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javafx-overview.html) package which is required for this `Browser` option to work.

---

However according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) you should always be using the latest version of JRE/JMeter so if you need to be able to render the response in the View Results Tree listener go for the following steps:

1. Download and install [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)
2. Set `PATH_TO_FX` environment variable pointing to the OpenJFX installation folder
3. Restart JMeter - at this point you should see the `Browser` option

Comment: I already installed OpenJFX and set path as "PATH_TO_FX" to "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\bin" but I dont see BROWSER in listener yet after jmeter relaunch.

Comment: You should use "lib" folder, not "bin" folder: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Answer (score 0):

[Browser option was removed](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63355) due to missing JavaFX suppport

> Bug 63355 - View Results Tree: Browser view option is not Available with Java 11

You can downgrade to Java 8 (which include library) or add Java FX library manually

> Felix Schumacher:
> You either have to downgrade to a Oracle Java -- which includes JavaFX, or you try to integrate JavaFX into a newer Java version. openjfx.io claims to have JavaFX versions for newer Java versions.